# Selenium "Please verify you are a human" Popup in Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I'm curious if anyone has found a work around for handling the random "Please Verify you are human" pop up in FireFox when using Selenium and BeautifulSoup. Currently, it pops up about every 500 or 1,000 URL requests, but I'd love an automated workaround.

My driver is just the default `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` with selenium. The pop up is a press AND hold button (picture below) which I've just done manually as I've seen it pop up. Any info would be great thanks!

[image]

Comment: Steps to repro?

Comment: You could remove the `time.sleep()` in this repo and run: https://github.com/aviolante/stockx_scraper/blob/master/01-url-scraper.py

Comment: Sorry to be vague about reproducing. If you just hit a list of URLs long enough and especially without `time.sleep()` then you'll run into this URL redirect.

Comment: you didn't add URL for this page so we can't test it. Did you try to use proxy servers and every page load with different proxy server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've figured out a workaround for this. Since the URL doesn't actually change / redirect when the 'Please verify you are human' popup occurs I've added a step prior to getting the elements with beautifulSoup.

For each URL in the list that is being scraped I do a `time.sleep(5.5)` to allow URL to fully load or for the verify popup to occur. Then, I interact with the URL and look for the verify indicator. For StockX it works like this: while true, try `soup.find('div', class_='page-title').text` and if it finds `'\nPlease verify you are a human\n'` then close browser and sleep (`driver.quit()` and `time.sleep(20)`) else scrape elements.

I dont have the full code written up to work but I do know I can detect if its a verify page as mentioned above. Something like this below maybe:

```
for url in url_list:
  for attempt in range(5):
    try:
      if soup.find('div', class_='page-title').text == '\nPlease verify you are a human\n':
        driver.quit()
        time.sleep(20)
      else:
        scrape_everything()
    except:
      print(f'Hit Verify Page Attempt Num.: {attempt}')
    else:
      break
  else:
    continue
```